# Conditional filling of rows

Tags: r

I'm sure this is simple but it (and a raging cold) has me stumped at the moment.  I have the following list, C1 & C2.  I want to remove the x's, replacing them with the other letter associated via the C1 number, giving the Desired C2 column result.  The non-x value will always be in the first position.

```
   C1 C2 DesiredC2
1   1  A         A
2   1  A         A
3   1  x         A
4   1  A         A
5   1  x         A
6   2  B         B
7   2  B         B
8   2  x         B
9   3  C         C
10  3  x         C
```

The dput() version of the first two columns is:

```
df2 <- structure(list(C1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
C2 = c("A", "A", "x", "A", "x", "B", "B", "x", "C", "x"), 
X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("C1","C2", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ave` rears it's ugly head again:

```
with(df2, ave(C2,C1,FUN=function(i) i[i!="x"][1])  )
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C"
```

...and taking into account `NA` values:

```
with(df2, ave(C2,C1,FUN=function(i) i[i!="x" & !is.na(i)][1])  )
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C"
```

To explain how this works, `ave` splits `C2` into groups defined by `C1`, and then returns the first non "x" value for `C2` for every entry in the group. I.e. -

```
i[i!="x"][1]
```

translates into

```
C2[C2 != "x"][1]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ugly and I'm not sure exactly how it works but it does work.  I just have to swing it around into the df.

Comment: @Lee_Kennedy - added some description of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

This would produce the desired result

```
df2$X <- with(df2, ifelse(C2 != "x", C2, unique(C2[C2 != "x"])[C1]))
```

or, if what you want to replace are "QC" entries in C2:

```
df2$X <- with(df2, ifelse(C2 != "QC", C2, unique(C2[C2 != "QC"])[C1]))
```

Edit after comment by OP in other answer:

```
df2$X <- with(df2, ifelse(C2 != "x", C2, LETTERS[C1]))
```

This will always give you the corresponding LETTER according to C1 where there are "x" in C2.

Edit #2 after another comment by OP

```
df2$X <- with(df2, ifelse(is.na(C2), LETTERS[C1], C2))    #for NA instead of "x"
```

Comment: It works with the demo data but when i try to apply it to the actual data set (I simplified it for clarity) the x's get replaced with NA.

Comment: NA is a special case and there are special functions to handle that. I'll include another way in my answer

Comment: No, sorry.  I feel like the Sorcerer's Apprentice.  Please forget about LETTERS.  In simplifying a complex df I have misled you to my need.  I think your first answer is the way to go but unique(C2[C2 != "x"])[C1]) returns NA when I try to use it in the larger df.  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Replace "x" with whatever you actually want to replace in C2 e.g. "QC". That should work then. I assume for this case, that all entries in C2 that you want to replace are exactly the same (like "QC") and not in the form of "product_name_QC" where product_name could change.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#Find the "x"s
xs = which(df2$C2=="x") 
#Now replace them
df2$C2[xs] = LETTERS[df2$C1[xs]]
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Just as a side note, this works fine but only as long as you are dealing with single capital letters A through Z only.

Comment: Ah, yes it did what I asked for, no it didn't do what I wanted. (!) The relationship between 1,2 & 3 and A,B & C is coincidental so I don't want an A always against a C1 value of 1.  I just want the x's replaced by their companion letter for a given value of C1.

Comment: beginneR makes an excellent point and has an answer below that does what you're after I think.

Comment: @Lee_Kennedy I'm not sure I understand you correct. What would like to see in column `X` if the first 5 rows of C1 were, say 5? still A or E or something else?

Comment: In real life column C2 will have two entries: results with a product name (say, cheese) and results labelled QC for quality control samples.  They will have a common reference number in column C1.  I want to remove the word 'QC' and replace it with 'cheese'. I seem to be making this more complicated.

Comment: So is it correct that all rows that have "cheese" in C2 share the same C1 number? Anyway, the approach with LETTERS doesnt seem to be suited for this task, since you are not interested in letters but in values of C2 that share the same C1, correct?

Comment: @beginneR Exactly.  In simplifying the df for clarity, I inadvertently created the impression that I wanted 1=A etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following will work for you... I have tried to make it generic one.. You can skip few steps...

**Edit**

```
df2_x = df2[df2$C2=='x',] #Take out rows with X
df2_nx = df2[df2$C2!='x',] #Take out rows without X


#Dummy Dataframe - Which is one to one map. Here C2 can have any value, character/number/string
structure(list(C1 = c(2L, 3L, 1L), C2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("C1", 
"C2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

  C1 C2
1  2  B
2  3  A
3  1  C

#Find out remaining colnames (except C2)
rem_colNames = setdiff(colnames(df2),'C2')
df2_x = merge(df2_x[,rem_colNames],mappingdf,by='C1')

#Combining both data.frame
df2 = rbind(df2_nx,df2_x)
```

Comment: Please see my comment above.  In trying to simplify my problem I have sent people off on a wild goose chase using LETTERS.  Sorry.